# How to handle edits that ask new questions to avoid duplicate closure

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52571930/1) today, which is a fairly common dupe in the [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) tag.  I closed the question, yet the user then [added a requirement to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52571930/3), making the duplicate not quite make sense.

I rolled back the question to the original version, and posted a comment telling the user to ask a new question rather than ask a new question in their current post.

The user then proceeded to completely remove their initial requirement from the question, and only kept the newest requirement, leaving the question in [its current form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571930/selecting-vector-of-2d-array-elements-from-column-index-vector).

I wanted to avoid berating a new contributor over and over about the same thing, so I finally opened the question (which with the edits really was no longer a duplicate), and answered, but I'm not sure I handled it correctly.

**My Question**: Once the user started editing the post so the duplicate no longer made sense, should I have:

A) Kept rolling back to the previous version

B) Re-opened

Comment: This is exactly what should have happened.  The OP took the closure as a cue to improve his question and is now happy with the answer.  So it is B.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think "we" (i.e. the community) get way too caught up in "the rules".  At the core, the primary rule of Stack Overflow is "ask a good question".  If the question is good, then it is worthy of being answered.  If it isn't, then it doesn't. And keep in mind that the primary users of the site aren't always the OP, but everyone else who visits the site.  If the question is useful, then trying to prevent it because the OP changed the question hurts anyone else who has the same problem.

So if you have a current question that isn't a duplicate and is a good and useful question, then it deserves an answer.  So if the question isn't a duplicate anymore, then reopen it.  If it is a duplicate of another question, then enlist some support to reopen/reclose it as a dup of the other question, or use your gold badge powers to edit the duplicate link to the new dup (assuming you have them)

There are a few caveats here:

- If the edit invalidated answers of the previous version of the question (assuming the original question was good and clear), then the edit should be rolled back
- If the user appears to be trying to circumvent a question ban by asking a completely different/unrelated question, the edit should be rolled back.
- If the user seems to be doing something shifty, then just flag for a mod and let them handle it.

Just to expand on the first bullet, "rolling back if the edit invalidates existing answers" is an oversimplification.  In practice, it greatly depends on the situation

- A User asks a good clear question, gets a good clear answer before it is closed as a duplicate.  The OP shouldn't be editing the question to change the question and invalidate the existing answer(s) since the original answers were done in good faith to address the original question.  Instead, the OP should be encouraged to ask a new question.
- But in cases where a poor question (especially one that is vague and/or unclear) is answered before getting marked as a duplicate, then the question OP edits the question to clear up the confusion and invalidates the existing speculative answer(s).  Here the edit is a good one since it clarified the question and made it a good on-topic question.  The answers don't need the same protection as the good faith answers previously mentioned.  So don't roll back these edits.

Comment: I agree with this.  I think most of the previous experiences I was basing my decision off of were questions that already had answers before the requirements were changed.  I think in this case, since I had almost instantly flagged as a dupe, the edits were not harmful at all.

Comment: One thing that missing here IMO is checking if the old revision is a useful signpost. If it is, the new question should definitely be asked as a new question, and OP should not be allowed to destroy the useful signpost.

Comment: "If the edit invalidated answers of the previous version of the question", why does it matters? The previous version of the question was not a good question and shouldn't have been answered. You are undermining your own argument about what SO cares about.

Comment: @Braiam you are right, but it depends on the situation.  A good and clear question that was answered, then edited should be rolled back.  A bad question that someone took a guess on shouldn't.